# Virtual Reality: Word for conflict in depth queue

Tags: 3d, virtual-reality, perception

I'm searching for a word that describes a conflict in the depth queue of a 3d projection.

Example:
[image: Example Picture]

A user has a distance of 2 Meter from a 3D Display. The 3D Displays projects an image of a ball 50 cm from the user. If now a pysical Object (like a Paper) is inserted in the middle between user and display (1 meter distance), than the projected ball should be in front of the object. But since the Paper blocks the display it is in front of the Ball.

So the "correct" depth queue would be (ball, Paper, display), but the user sees (Paper, ball, display).

What is the name for this conflict in the depth queue which destroys the 3d illusion?

ps: I think depth queue is the correct term, correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: If you know better tags please edit: virtual-reality and 3d-diplays would work but don't exist (yet)

Answer (score 2):

The process you're describing is called "Occlusion Culling" and the "depth queue" is actually called a "z-buffer." There isn't a specific word (at least not a well-accepted one) for having a incorrect ordering of a z-buffer or an incomplete culling of occlusions.

Comment: I didn't knew these words, thank you. They might even be the most correct ones, but they don't really apply in this situation. Occlusion Culling is used in the Processing of graphical objects. But i am talking about a pysical object and a 3d screen. (Like a person standing in front of the screen at a movie theater)

Comment: Well that's just occlusion. Occlusion culling is the removal of occluded faces from the render pipeline

Comment: I give you the reward by default (since there are no other answers). I still suspect there might be a better word in the virtual reality, or optical psychology community though. Anyway thank you!